# Visual Studio 2010 Find and Replace Regular Expression Help (for php short tags)

Tags: regex, visual-studio, replace

I have some php scripts that I need to short tags with their full blown alternative, I'm using vs.php for visual studio 2010 and what to do a Find And Replace using regular expressions. so far I have the following:

```
Find RegEx: \<\?=\({(.+)}\)\?\>
Replace RegEx: \<\?php echo \1 \?\>
```

This works fine if there is only one short tag in a line but if there are two or more then it doesn't work properly, it finds the last instance of ")\?>" and I just want to find the next. eg.

```
Test: <?=($foo)?>
Result: <?php echo $foo ?>
OK

Test: <?=($foo)?> <?=($bar)?>
Result: <?php echo $foo)?> <?=($bar ?>
Not OK
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want is a *minimal match*--what most other regex flavors call a *non-greedy* match.  In VS you do that by using `@` or `#` in place of `*` or `+`:

```
Find RegEx: \<\?=\({(.#)}\)\?\>
```